# Using Different Font Styles in TextView

Tags: java, android, file

I can display the contents of a file in a `TextView` by adding the file under the raw folder and reading the file. It works fine. But all of the contents in the file look the same. I want to differentiate titles and the contents by introducing Font styles.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you want to apply different formatting to different parts of your text in TextView. But As I know, TextView doesn't supports multiple styles (formatting) (yet). Whatever the formatting you apply, will be applied to the whole text in TextView. To use different formatting, you can use the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

**Update:**

This functionality is available for EditText (I saw it too late), see this link for details; http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WebView` instead as your text is static you can format it to create a htmlPage and then display it in `webview` something like this

```
WebView mView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.help_text);
mView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/help.html");
mView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```